# An Angular ng-zorro table should add specific columns to overflow-x: scroll

Tags: angular, typescript, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I have tried to make the [Angular ng-zorro](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en) table's only columns 1 (Assignment Number) to 4 (Total) should be a fixed and  adding scroll-x and  the table header color red from columns 5 to 18 (let column of scrollableColumns), but its not working correctly, dose anyone know the solution?
Thanks

the table HTML code looks as follows.

```
    <nz-table #fixedTable [nzData]="listOfData" [nzScroll]="{ x: '1150px' }" class="custom-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th nz-th nzWidth="220px" nzLeft="0">Assignment Number</th>
      <th nz-th nzWidth="220px">Status</th>
      <th nz-th nzWidth="220px">Client Name</th>
      <th nz-th nzWidth="220px">Total</th>
      
      <th nz-th *ngFor="let column of scrollableColumns" [nzWidth]="'220px'">{{ column }}</th>
      
      <th nz-th nzWidth="220px" nzRight="0">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of fixedTable.data">
      <td nz-td nzLeft>{{ data.AssignmentNumber }}</td>
      <td nz-td>{{ data.Status }}</td>
      <td nz-td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      <td nz-td>{{ data.total }}</td>
      
      <td nz-td *ngFor="let column of scrollableColumns" [ngStyle]="{ 'min-width': '220px' }">{{ data[column] }}</td>
      
      <td nz-td nzRight>
        <a>action</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

css

```
   .custom-table .ant-table-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.custom-table .ant-table-thead > tr > th:nth-child(5) {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

.custom-table .ant-table-tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5) {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

.ts

```
scrollableColumns: string[] = Array.from(
    { length: 18 },
    (_, i) => `Column ${i + 1}`
  );
```